# How do I call an Oracle package function using EDM in .NET 4 from Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, oracle, odp.net, odac

I am using Visual Studio 2010, .NET 4, Oracle Database 11gR2, and Oracle ODT 11.2.0.3.60 Beta 2 (but I see the same behaviour with ODT 11.2.0.3.20).

My schema has a package defined as follows:

```
create or replace 
package dummy1
as
  procedure proc1(
      asd varchar2);
  function func1(
      sdf varchar2)
    return number;
end dummy1;

create or replace 
package body dummy1
as
procedure proc1(
    asd varchar2)
as
begin
  /* TODO implementation required */
  null;
end proc1;
function func1(
    sdf varchar2)
  return number
as
begin
  /* TODO implementation required */
  return null;
end func1;
end dummy1;
```

If I make an EDM for the schema, I can see both `proc1` and `func1` in the `Stored Procedure` folder under `Model.Store` in the Model Browser. I am able to do a "Function Import" on `proc1`, and then call this from my .NET program. However, I am unable to do the same for `func1`.

Is there a limitation on functions within packages in ODP, or am I missing something here?

Comment: Hi Allan,I realise this is an old post but I am just wondering if you ever managed to do this? i.e. Calling procedure contained in a package? Thanks, Tomás

Comment: @Tomás, no I didn't get anywhere with this! I generally get the impression that Oracle stored procedures aren't well-supported from .NET. I think the best solution might be to write my own wrapper that gets procedure definitions from the data dictionary. Having said that, I've since found that what I want to do is much easier from Python!

Comment: Thanks Allan! Thats a pity. Python isnt an option for me unfortunatley. Have to stay within confines of what the client is comfortable with which is .Net. BTW, well done Oracle! If they are going to support procedures at all then why stop half way and not support those within packages. Ohh well, *sigh*. Thanks again. T

Comment: Apparently DotConnect for Oracle handles procedures and functions much better than Oracle's library, but it's not free unfortunately. They do have a free trial though, so if you have a budget it might be worth a look.

Comment: great. Thanks Allan. I'll check it out!